# How does the Pass-The-Ticket attack work?

Tags: active-directory

Generally, for a TGS request, we are required to have the corresponding TGT ticket, the user blob encrypted with TGT session key, and SPN service. It means that the attacker should know the TGT session key to proceed with the PTT attack in order to request for the TGS ticket. If the TGT Session key is not required, then, we can simply get the TGT tickets of pre-auth disabled users, however, we are required to know the TGT session key in this case, that's why we cannot accomplish TGS request.

How PTT works without knowing the TGT session key as this is theoretically impossible?

Comment: https://www.beyondtrust.com/resources/glossary/what-are-pass-the-ticket-attacks and https://www.picussecurity.com/resource/blog/t1550.003-pass-the-ticket-adversary-use-of-alternate-authentication

Answer (score 0):

If an attacker gains access to a user's credentials or TGT using credential dumping, they can use these credentials directly to impersonate the user and request service tickets without needing to know the TGT session key.

In a Silver Ticket attack, the attacker can forge service tickets for a specific service without needing the TGT session key. By obtaining the service account's password hash, the attacker can create and use forged service tickets to access the targeted service. This technique is a lot harder though.

Comment: Let's think that preauth is disabled for user A. The attacker can obtain the credential of this user through simply sending AS-REQ request to the KDC and the KDC will respond with the TGT. Then does that mean we can perform PTT to any preauth disabled accounts?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. That is why having preauth is very important.